# Creating a URL filter for a proxy in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, proxy, webapp2

I've been working on a small project which requires me to create a proxy with access to only a few sites.

Am using the code from here: https://github.com/labnol/google-proxy

Now, basically am a PHP guy, but haven't found anything as better as the above for setting up a web proxy server.

What I need here is:

1. A way to filter out URLs. Like I want people to access only the sites I allow.
2. In the allowed sites, I'd like to block certain scripts. e.g. On wikipedia.org, the person shouldn't be allowed to login.

Am a complete noob in Python. Can anyone suggest me something here, or provide a code snippet which I can use?

Thanks! :)

P.S.: For a PHP version, I've tried using Glype and miniProxy. But not as good as the one I mentioned. They break the CSS/JS of the websites.

Answer (score 1):

You may install [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) and write your own filtering rules.

Comment: I was trying that only! Installed it. Trying to get hold of the conf file. There's too much in it!

Comment: Thanks for this.. but I need a web based solution.